# Bluez 5.X and Ubuntu 14.0X

Tags: bluetooth

Has anyone been able to successfully install Bluez 5.X on Ubuntu 14.04? I need to upgrade it to use a new Bluetooth mouse, but I've tried several times and it seems to break the OS. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What did you try and what was the problem?

Comment: @Pilot6 I confirm that I have seen this too. It seems to not install successfully (in the process, disabling the sound of the device) and it breaks the package manager. Forcing a purge of BlueZ 5 and then reinstalling BlueZ 4 seems to fix things, but there is definitely something going wrong with the BlueZ 5 installation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge bluez # remove old versions
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vidplace7/bluez5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bluez
```

This adds the PPA for Bluez 5 and installs BlueZ.

Comment: Please note that this breaks "all" graphical User Interfaces, as those are programmed to work with bluez version 4.

Comment: Additionally gattool is not part of that ppa right now.
there is some discussion about wether to include it in bluez5 or have it in a seperate package.
Debian and redhat/fedora seem to have it included for now.
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=720486