# How should BlueZ 5 be installed?

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I'm trying to get a bluetooth keyboard paired via terminal in Ubuntu Touch (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701978/how-can-a-bluetooth-keyboard-that-requires-a-code-entry-be-paired-in-the-termina) for more details). For this purpose, I need the executable `bluetoothctl`, which appears to be provided by BlueZ 5 (as opposed to BlueZ 4).

I have tried installing BlueZ 5 on desktop and it caused many problems with the package manager and nuked the sound of the computer (forcing a purge of BlueZ 5 and reinstalling BlueZ 4 fixed things). I have tried installing BlueZ 5 on my Ubuntu phone (Aquaris E4.5) and it bricked it (necessitating a reflash), so I'm really not sure how I should try to install this. What I've tried to do is as follows:

```
sudo apt-get remove bluez
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vidplace7/bluez5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-tools
```

I note that [others](https://askubuntu.com/questions/662347/bluez-5-x-and-ubuntu-14-0x) appear to be seeing problems with BlueZ 5 also.

What should I do instead?

On desktop, I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and on phone, I am using Ubuntu 15.04 - armhf (20151118-205525).

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add information about the releases/images you use on the phone and desktop?

Comment: @LiveWireBT Thanks for the suggestion. I've added details on the system versions I'm using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Ubuntu Touch OTA9 release includes Bluez5 and it enables pairing with ThinkPad keyboards. Here's the little BQ Aquaris E4.5 acting almost as a palmtop.

[image]

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid BlueZ5 gets installed by upgrading from OTA8 to OTA9.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a Live version of Ubuntu 15.10 as it has Bluez 5 and see if it functions to your liking using the "Try without Installing Ubuntu" option