# Install bluetooth or bluez-utils packages fails using bluez-5.37 (or bluez-4.101)

Tags: apt, package-management, bluetooth, dbus, bluez

I have compiled bluez 5.37 from sources, and installed it.
I would like to install the package bluez-utils, which depends on bluez.

```
sudo apt-get install bluez-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  bluetooth bluez bluez-alsa bluez-gstreamer
Suggested packages:
  bluez-hcidump
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bluetooth bluez bluez-alsa bluez-gstreamer bluez-utils
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/777 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,497 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Unfortunately, when I try to, it tries to install bluez 
4.101-0ubuntu13.1 which does not install correctly on my host.

```
Selecting previously unselected package bluez.
(Reading database ... 557098 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bluez_4.101-0ubuntu13.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bluez (4.101-0ubuntu13.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package bluetooth.
Preparing to unpack .../bluetooth_4.101-0ubuntu13.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking bluetooth (4.101-0ubuntu13.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package bluez-alsa:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../bluez-alsa_4.101-0ubuntu13.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bluez-alsa:amd64 (4.101-0ubuntu13.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package bluez-gstreamer.
Preparing to unpack .../bluez-gstreamer_4.101-0ubuntu13.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bluez-gstreamer (4.101-0ubuntu13.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package bluez-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../bluez-utils_4.101-0ubuntu13.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking bluez-utils (4.101-0ubuntu13.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up bluez (4.101-0ubuntu13.1) ...
reload: Job is not running: dbus
invoke-rc.d: initscript dbus, action "force-reload" failed.
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript bluetooth, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluetooth:
bluetooth depends on bluez; however:
Package bluez is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package bluetooth (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
...
```

In another attempt, I [tried to install bluez 5 from packaging, using this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/662347/bluez-5-x-and-ubuntu-14-0x) but it failed too

> Try this: sudo apt-get purge bluez # remove old versions sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vidplace7/bluez5 sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install bluez

Again, I get a dbus force-reload failure:

```
Preparing to unpack .../bluez_5.35.0+upstream-201601200846~rev18516~pkg9~ubuntu14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bluez (5.35.0+upstream-201601200846~rev18516~pkg9~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up bluez (5.35.0+upstream-201601200846~rev18516~pkg9~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
reload: Job is not running: dbus
invoke-rc.d: initscript dbus, action "force-reload" failed.
bluetooth start/running
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
```

Note also that my system is up-to-date. Just to make sure, I tried to install bluez after a cleanup and update:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge bluez.*
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install bluez
...
Setting up bluez (4.101-0ubuntu13.1) ...
reload: Job is not running: dbus
invoke-rc.d: initscript dbus, action "force-reload" failed.
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript bluetooth, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit   status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
bluez
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

In /etc/init.d there is a bluetooth script. If I launch it, it does not complain, but the logs show that actually it is not working:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
 * Stopping bluetooth                                                    [ OK ] 
 * Starting bluetooth                                                    [ OK ] 



$ dmesg | tail 
[523602.147016] init: bluetooth main process (2672) terminated with status 1
[523602.147023] init: bluetooth main process ended, respawning
[523602.162789] init: bluetooth main process (2681) terminated with status 1
[523602.162797] init: bluetooth respawning too fast, stopped
```

So **how can I install bluetooth on my system?** *I don't care that much if I have bluez 4 or bluez 5*, but I want to be able to install bluez-utils one way or another...

Thanks

Comment: There is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1301962), according to comments there this should be fixed if you have updated upstart. Is your system up-to-date? `sudo purge bluez.*; sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Yes, I confirm I am up to date (just checked again), but unfortunately that does not solve the issue. I'm not sure the bug report is solved either.

Comment: Does the force-reload actually fail in the second case or does the install carry on? Some `bluez.postinst` have a line `invoke-rc.d dbus force-reload || true` so if it fails the install still completes - check yours with `cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/bluez.postinst`. If the install completes then it should be ok, `force-reload` just reloads the config, you can do the same with `/etc/init.d/bluez restart` or just reboot once.

Comment: No, the force-reload fails once again.
    Setting up bluez (4.101-0ubuntu13.1) ...
    reload: Job is not running: dbus
    invoke-rc.d: initscript dbus, action "force-reload" failed.
    start: Job failed to start
    invoke-rc.d: initscript bluetooth, action "start" failed.
   dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure):
   subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Besides, there is no /etc/init.d/bluez on my system, only a /etc/init.d/bluetooth. But it does not seem to be starting ok.

Comment: I'll edit the question for clarity :)

Comment: Try adding `|| true` to the end of the `invoke-rc.d dbus force-reload` line in `bluez.postinst`

Comment: Months later, after another upgrade, and
`sudo purge blue*; sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, I finally manage to installe bluez-utils :)
Actually, there is still that **invoke-rc.d: initscript dbus, action "force-reload" failed** but it continues.
`
Setting up bluez (4.101-0ubuntu13.1) ...
reload: Job is not running: dbus
invoke-rc.d: initscript dbus, action "force-reload" failed.
bluetooth start/running, process 21366
Setting up bluez-cups (4.101-0ubuntu13.1) ...
`
and `dpkg -l | grep blue` shows only fully installed packaged, no failures.

Comment: so, I'll check if it really works now, and if so mark the issue as solved.

Comment: Yes, it works ! So cool !
@bain, you basically had the solution, let me know how I can "vote" for your solution!

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that bluez wouldn't install correctly on the system with message

> reload: Job is not running: dbus
>   invoke-rc.d: initscript dbus, action "force-reload" failed.
>   start: Job failed to start
>   invoke-rc.d: initscript bluetooth, action "start" failed.

In **February**, an upgrade did not solve the problem, but months later now in **August**, it does. You simply need to do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bluez*; sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then re-install.

```
$ sudo apt-get install bluez-utils
...
Setting up bluez (4.101-0ubuntu13.1) ...
reload: Job is not running: dbus
invoke-rc.d: initscript dbus, action "force-reload" failed.
bluetooth start/running, process 21366
```

Note that the reload for bluez "fails" but the package still installs correctly.

```
ii  bluez                                             4.101-0ubuntu13.1                            amd64        Bluetooth tools and daemons
```

Comment: I get an error: **sudo: purge: command not found**

Comment: On my side, I just did this with the `--reinstall` flag and it worked: `sudo apt-get install bluez-utils --reinstall`. I had an installation failure from trying to install bluez 5 from ubuntu 14 but now it is restored.